# RDP to Low Priority Ubuntu node on Batch Service Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I am trying to RDP to a low priority ubuntu 16.04 LTS node on batch services in MS AZURE but the RDP connection doesn't go through. I can ssh. 
What I have done so far:

1. Set up the batch service, created a pool and created a low priority node.
2. SSHed to it and followed instructions on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop). But I cannot do the "Create a Network Security Group rule for Remote Desktop traffic" as I cannot find a NSG setting anywhere related to the low priority node. May be that could be the problem?

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Batch allows a node user with network connectivity to connect externally to a compute node in a Batch pool. For example, a user can connect by Remote Desktop (RDP) on port 3389 to a compute node in a Windows pool. Similarly, by default, a user can connect by Secure Shell (SSH) on port 22 to a compute node in a Linux pool.

You may need to change endpoint configuration consists of one or more network address translation (NAT) pools of frontend ports. Each NAT pool configuration includes one or more network security group (NSG) rules. Each NSG rule allows or denies certain network traffic to the endpoint. Refer: [Configure or disable remote access to compute nodes in an Azure Batch pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/batch/pool-endpoint-configuration)